# Django REST Framework relations

Tags: python, django

when i make my api using the Hyper Linked method i get this error.

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /api/order/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "customer-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/order/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "customer-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

This is my serializer.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import *



class OrderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'customer', 'orderid', 'date', 'status')
```

It cant find the relation between customer and order in the order serializer, when i write the code without the customer field it works. Is there any way i can query this?

And this is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
 
from rest_framework import viewsets

from api.models import *
from api.serializer import *


class OrderView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

I get the same error when i try to access the orderitem api and the shipping adress api. Any ideas?

And here are my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from api import views
from rest_framework import routers

router.register('order', views.OrderView, basename='Order')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

This is the model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    orderid = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer) + ", " + str(self.orderid)
```

Comment: let's try to reduce this... we only need the things relating to orders and customers, and we do need to see the models

Comment: i get the same error for every other field as well and my models.py file i fairly big.

Comment: SO guidelines state a MINIMUM reproduceable example of the problem in your question. Complicating it with everything else is lowering your chances of getting an answer. Like i said, reduce the code in this to only include relevant details to the problem, and also include RELEVANT models and actually the relevant URL configs are needed for this particular issue

Comment: okey but the model is related to other models.

Comment: The customer model / serializer / view / url is relevant here, along with the order

Comment: idk what you mean man, do you know why i get this error?

Comment: Yes but I do not have the information I need to fix it. I need the Customer related code